# How can I add a field that count the number of the records retrieved by my query? Why am I obtaining this error message?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, rdbms

I am not so into SQL and I have the following doubt trying to change a query (I am using MySql as DB).

So I have this query:

```
SELECT 
        MD.id                                                           AS market_id,
        MD.market_name                                                  AS market_name,
        CN.id                                                           AS commodity_details_id,
        CD.commodity_name_en                                            AS commodity_name_en,
        CN.commodity_name                                               AS commodity_name, 
        CD.image_link                                                   AS image_link,            
        CN.description                                                  AS description,
        MD_CD.id                                                        AS price_serie_id,
        MCPS.avg_price                                                  AS today_avg_price,
        YMCPS.avg_price                                                 AS yesterday_avg_price,

        CASE WHEN MCPS.market_commodity_details_id IS NOT NULL
                THEN 
                        MCPS.currency
                ELSE
                        YMCPS.currency
        END AS currency,

        CASE WHEN MCPS.market_commodity_details_id IS NOT NULL
                THEN 
                        MCPS.measure_unit
                ELSE
                        YMCPS.measure_unit
                END AS measure_unit

FROM MarketDetails_CommodityDetails AS MD_CD

INNER JOIN MarketDetails AS MD 
    ON MD_CD.market_details_id = MD.id

INNER JOIN CommodityDetails as CD 
    ON MD_CD.commodity_details_id = CD.id

INNER JOIN CommodityName AS CN 
    ON CD.id=CN.commodity_details_id


LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        Market_Commodity_Price_Series.id AS price_series_id,
        market_commodity_details_id
        , avg_price
        , CU.ISO_4217_cod      AS currency
        , MU.unit_name         AS measure_unit
    FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series
    INNER JOIN MeasureUnit AS MU
    ON Market_Commodity_Price_Series.measure_unit_id = MU.id
    INNER JOIN Currency AS CU 
    ON Market_Commodity_Price_Series.currency_id = CU.id 
    WHERE price_date = CURDATE()
) AS MCPS 
ON MD_CD.id = MCPS.market_commodity_details_id

LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        Market_Commodity_Price_Series.id AS price_series_id,
        market_commodity_details_id
        , avg_price
        , CU.ISO_4217_cod      AS currency
        , MU.unit_name         AS measure_unit
    FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series
    INNER JOIN MeasureUnit AS MU
    ON Market_Commodity_Price_Series.measure_unit_id = MU.id
    INNER JOIN Currency AS CU 
    ON Market_Commodity_Price_Series.currency_id = CU.id 
    WHERE price_date = ADDDATE(CURDATE(), -1) 
) AS YMCPS 
ON MD_CD.id = YMCPS.market_commodity_details_id

WHERE 
   MD_CD.commodity_details_id = 4
AND 
    MD.localization_id = 2
```

that is returning 2 records like these representing the markets where a specific commodity is sold, something like this:

```
market_id            market_name                    commodity_details_id      commodity_name_en            commodity_name        image_link                                                                                                                                                                                                      description price_serie_id       today_avg_price      yesterday_avg_price  currency measure_unit                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4                    Tambacounda Market N1          4                         Red onion                    Red onion             https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blablabla.appspot.com/o/img%2Ficons%2Fagrimarket%2Fcommodity%2Fonion-red.png?alt=media&token=4ec9de4e-6e5a-4198-9bcd-21b692760618              Red onion   24                   20,15                18,94                XOF      kilogram                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
5                    Tambacounda Market N2          4                         Red onion                    Red onion             https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blablabla.appspot.com/o/img%2Ficons%2Fagrimarket%2Fcommodity%2Fonion-red.png?alt=media&token=4ec9de4e-6e5a-4198-9bcd-21b692760618              Red onion   28                   13,7                 16,2                 XOF      kilogram
```

Ok I want to add a new field that represents the number of markets in which this commodity is avaiable (basically the number of retrieved records), so I tried to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
        MD.id                                                           AS market_id,
        MD.market_name                                                  AS market_name,
        count(MD.id)                                                AS market_total_number,
        CN.id                                                           AS commodity_details_id,
        CD.commodity_name_en                                            AS commodity_name_en,
        CN.commodity_name                                               AS commodity_name, 
        CD.image_link                                                   AS image_link,            
        CN.description                                                  AS description,
        MD_CD.id                                                        AS price_serie_id,
        MCPS.avg_price                                                  AS today_avg_price,
        YMCPS.avg_price                                                 AS yesterday_avg_price,

        CASE WHEN MCPS.market_commodity_details_id IS NOT NULL
                THEN 
                        MCPS.currency
                ELSE
                        YMCPS.currency
        END AS currency,

        CASE WHEN MCPS.market_commodity_details_id IS NOT NULL
                THEN 
                        MCPS.measure_unit
                ELSE
                        YMCPS.measure_unit
                END AS measure_unit

FROM MarketDetails_CommodityDetails AS MD_CD

INNER JOIN MarketDetails AS MD 
    ON MD_CD.market_details_id = MD.id

INNER JOIN CommodityDetails as CD 
    ON MD_CD.commodity_details_id = CD.id

INNER JOIN CommodityName AS CN 
    ON CD.id=CN.commodity_details_id


LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        Market_Commodity_Price_Series.id AS price_series_id,
        market_commodity_details_id
        , avg_price
        , CU.ISO_4217_cod      AS currency
        , MU.unit_name         AS measure_unit
    FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series
    INNER JOIN MeasureUnit AS MU
    ON Market_Commodity_Price_Series.measure_unit_id = MU.id
    INNER JOIN Currency AS CU 
    ON Market_Commodity_Price_Series.currency_id = CU.id 
    WHERE price_date = CURDATE()
) AS MCPS 
ON MD_CD.id = MCPS.market_commodity_details_id

LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        Market_Commodity_Price_Series.id AS price_series_id,
        market_commodity_details_id
        , avg_price
        , CU.ISO_4217_cod      AS currency
        , MU.unit_name         AS measure_unit
    FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series
    INNER JOIN MeasureUnit AS MU
    ON Market_Commodity_Price_Series.measure_unit_id = MU.id
    INNER JOIN Currency AS CU 
    ON Market_Commodity_Price_Series.currency_id = CU.id 
    WHERE price_date = ADDDATE(CURDATE(), -1) 
) AS YMCPS 
ON MD_CD.id = YMCPS.market_commodity_details_id

WHERE 
   MD_CD.commodity_details_id = 4
AND 
    MD.localization_id = 2
```

I simply added this **SELECT** to the retrievd fields list:

```
count(MD.id) AS market_total_number,
```

because my idea is to count the retrieved records, but performing my query now I am obtaining this error message:

```
#42000In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'digital_services_DB.MD.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue and obtained the desired result?

Comment: You can't use aggregation without a group by if you select anything *besides* the aggregation function (as the error clearly states).

Comment: `count(M.id) over (partition by columns)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to create a select with aggregation functions like count and also retrieve any field, you have to use group by.

You can read more about it in:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

So if you add this at the end of your query it will work.

```
GROUP BY
MD.id                       
,MD.market_name      
,CN.id               
,CD.commodity_name_en
,CN.commodity_name   
,CD.image_link        
,CN.description      
,MD_CD.id            
,MCPS.avg_price      
,YMCPS.avg_price
```

Answer (score 1):

When using an aggregation function the group by is mandatory.
try this

```
SELECT  count(market_id) AS market_total_number,
    market_id, 
    market_name,
    market_total_number,
    commodity_details_id,
    commodity_name_en,
    commodity_name, 
    image_link,    
    description,
    price_serie_id,  
    today_avg_price, 
    yesterday_avg_price,
    currency ,
    measure_units
FROM (  
SELECT 
        MD.id                                                           AS market_id,
        MD.market_name                                                  AS market_name,
        count(MD.id)                                                AS market_total_number,
        CN.id                                                           AS commodity_details_id,
        CD.commodity_name_en                                            AS commodity_name_en,
        CN.commodity_name                                               AS commodity_name, 
        CD.image_link                                                   AS image_link,            
        CN.description                                                  AS description,
        MD_CD.id                                                        AS price_serie_id,
        MCPS.avg_price                                                  AS today_avg_price,
        YMCPS.avg_price                                                 AS yesterday_avg_price,

        CASE WHEN MCPS.market_commodity_details_id IS NOT NULL
                THEN 
                        MCPS.currency
                ELSE
                        YMCPS.currency
        END AS currency,

        CASE WHEN MCPS.market_commodity_details_id IS NOT NULL
                THEN 
                        MCPS.measure_unit
                ELSE
                        YMCPS.measure_unit
                END AS measure_unit

FROM MarketDetails_CommodityDetails AS MD_CD

INNER JOIN MarketDetails AS MD 
    ON MD_CD.market_details_id = MD.id

INNER JOIN CommodityDetails as CD 
    ON MD_CD.commodity_details_id = CD.id

INNER JOIN CommodityName AS CN 
    ON CD.id=CN.commodity_details_id


LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        Market_Commodity_Price_Series.id AS price_series_id,
        market_commodity_details_id
        , avg_price
        , CU.ISO_4217_cod      AS currency
        , MU.unit_name         AS measure_unit
    FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series
    INNER JOIN MeasureUnit AS MU
    ON Market_Commodity_Price_Series.measure_unit_id = MU.id
    INNER JOIN Currency AS CU 
    ON Market_Commodity_Price_Series.currency_id = CU.id 
    WHERE price_date = CURDATE()
) AS MCPS 
ON MD_CD.id = MCPS.market_commodity_details_id

LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        Market_Commodity_Price_Series.id AS price_series_id,
        market_commodity_details_id
        , avg_price
        , CU.ISO_4217_cod      AS currency
        , MU.unit_name         AS measure_unit
    FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series
    INNER JOIN MeasureUnit AS MU
    ON Market_Commodity_Price_Series.measure_unit_id = MU.id
    INNER JOIN Currency AS CU 
    ON Market_Commodity_Price_Series.currency_id = CU.id 
    WHERE price_date = ADDDATE(CURDATE(), -1) 
) AS YMCPS 
ON MD_CD.id = YMCPS.market_commodity_details_id

WHERE 
   MD_CD.commodity_details_id = 4
AND 
    MD.localization_id = 2
) base
group by    market_id, 
        market_name,
        market_total_number,
        commodity_details_id,
        commodity_name_en,
        commodity_name, 
        image_link,    
        description,
        price_serie_id,  
        today_avg_price, 
        yesterday_avg_price,
        currency ,
        measure_units
```